# how to give a style for angularjs selectbox scroll?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In my project I am using angularjs select box.I need to give a custom style scroll bar for the select box. Using jquery scrollpane I found what I want. But while implementing that in angularjs selctbox its not working

Here is the link [click here](http://www.roblaplaca.com/docs/custom-selectbox/)  In this selectbox with scrollbar. I want to implement this in angularjs

Please give me an idea for this

here is my code

```
<select class="custom"  ng-options="sb.ID as sb.NAME for sb in Students|orderBy:'NAME'" ng-model="selectedStudents" ng-change="onChange(selectedStudents)">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                          </select>
```

Script

```
$(function() 
{
     $(".custom").is(function() 
        {                   
            var sb = new SelectBox({
                    selectbox: $(this),
                    height: 150,
                    width: 300                   

            });
    });

    });
```

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar Maybe this will help you a little bit

Comment: but this is for page scroll bar. I want inside selectbox

Comment: <select class="scrollme"  ng-options="sb.ID as sb.NAME for sb in Students|orderBy:'NAME'" ng-model="selectedStudents" ng-change="onChange(selectedStudents)">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                          </select>

Comment: i have tried like this still its not working